# Why Theme.of(context) telling me to check that the value isn't 'null' before dereferencing it?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I set custom theme for my App in  MaterialApp. when I'm try to use it with the below syntax, it's showing an error. What might be the reason?

```
colors: [
              Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              Theme.of(context).accentColor
            ],
```

Here is my  ***ThemeData*** to the ***MaterialApp*** constructor.

```
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Medbo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: AppColor.colorPrimary1,
          accentColor: AppColor.colorPrimary2,
        ),
        // home: Home(),
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes:{
          '/': (_)=>Home(),

        }
    );
```

When I'm trying to use it in my Scaffold ->

```
    return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
      flexibleSpace: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.topRight,
            colors: [
              Theme.of(context).primaryColor,     // error showing here
              Theme.of(context).accentColor      // error showing here
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Here I set my color properties  ->

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class AppColor{
  static final Color colorPrimary1 = Color.fromRGBO(30,81,126,1.0);
  static final Color colorPrimary2 = Color.fromRGBO(28, 117, 149, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: I would like to check your class AppColor.

Comment: hey,  just added the AppColor class

Comment: Thank you. Did you migrate to nullSafety?

Comment: Not sure about that. what I did was change my channel `stable` to `master` and upgrade my flutter SDK version & my pubspec.yaml file also.

Comment: The code you have shown above is working fine with me, but what you have shown in your screenshot is different. I recommend using nullSafety operator ! or ?.

Comment: I tried it on the Stack as well. It is working in both cases.

Comment: Not really familiar with nullSafety. it would be great if you tell me where should I use those nullSafty operator `!` or `?`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235734/discussion-between-ashiq-khan-and-tuhin).

Comment: The problem was in his Flutter. After the reinstallation of Flutter. Everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because of dart's new update, you should use null safety. this means that you must either put ! or ? in front of a variable to know that it may be null, or you should intialize it first before using it to avoid further bugs that it may cause later. for more information you can read dart's official documentation for null-safety [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety).